# How to specify a folder whith googledrive R package?

Tags: r, internal-server-error

I need to list many image files with his google ID, I find googledrive package in R and the next function  that do it but it chashes with a error message (I suposse because a have more than 30.000 "jpeg" files in many folders):

```
library(googledrive)

photos <- drive_find(type = "jpeg")
```

Can I specify the folder to run drive_find() function?; I was looking but I don´t find the solution.

I really apreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the next code was the solution for me:

```
library(googledrive)

Fotos <- drive_ls(as_id("here the ID of the specific Folder"))
```

These code download a drible with files in these folder and his ID.